# Is this possible to modifying the .sty file?

Tags: patching

Interested to modifying the fontawesome.sty file?

Comment: Are you asking if someone is interested in modifying the file? What would be the purpose? What modifications are you interested in doing? Is this part of a project? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nope it's not part of project but want to include the simple Skype command.

Comment: According to the [`package documentation`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf), Xavier Danaux is responsible for the LaTeX code and Dave Gandy  for the font and icons design; in the documentation you can find an e-mail address for Xavier Danaux, so you can e-mail him and kindly ask him to include the Skype icon.

Comment: _Please_ have a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and optimally at our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) as well. You’re not making it very easy to answer your questions. This site works differently from “normal” forums, but it’s a very productive way of working if everybody makes a little effort.